# checking validity of a list og urls using GET

Tags: r, url, get

i have a .csv file of URLS that i need to validate.

i want to apply GET of httr to every row of the data frame.

```
 > websites
          website
1   www.msn.com
2   www.wazl.com
3  www.amazon.com
4 www.rifapro.com
```

I did find similar questions and tried to apply the provided answers; however not working.

```
> apply(websites, 1, transform, result=GET(websites$website))


  Error: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE


> apply(websites, websites[,1], GET())
Error in handle_url(handle, url, ...) : 
  Must specify at least one of url or handle
```

i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
websites <- read.table(header=T, text="website
1   www.msn.com
2   www.wazl.com
3  www.amazon.com
4 www.rifapro.com")
library(httr)
urls <- paste0(ifelse(grepl("^https?://", websites$website, ig=T), "", "http://"),
          websites$website)
lst <- lapply(unique(tolower(urls)), function(url) try(HEAD(url), silent = T))
names(lst) <- urls
sapply(lst, function(x) if (inherits(x, "try-error")) -999 else status_code(x))
# http://www.msn.com    http://www.wazl.com  http://www.amazon.com http://www.rifapro.com 
#                200                   -999                    405                   -999
```

No need for a `GET` request imho.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt help. it is working on the dataset i provided here but not on the larger one i have. it is giving -999 to all however some are valid

Comment: @Rifa1234 Do you have an internet connection?

Comment: @Rifa1234 Besides that: e.g. the error messages in `lst[1:3]` should give a hint on what the problem is. My guess: the urls are malformed.

Comment: I am running it again on a smaller sample. i do have one extra question: i am trying to print it as a column in the dataframe to identify which is working and which is not.

Answer (score 0):

@LukeA gave me the answer and i just altered it to the below to generate a dataframe rather than a list. Thank you LukeA

```
urls <- paste0(ifelse(grepl("^https?://", websitm$WEBSITE, ig=T), "", "http://"),
    websitm$WEBSITE )
    lst <- lapply(unique(tolower(urls)), function(url) try(HEAD(url), silent = T))
    a<- list(lst,urls)
b<- as.data.frame(sapply(a, rbind))
b$outcome<- sapply(b$V1, function(x) if (inherits(x, "try-error")) -999 else status_code(x))
```

After refining the above code:

```
website<- read.csv(file= "path")
website<- website[!duplicated(website$Website),]
websitm<- website
websitm$Website <- paste0(ifelse(grepl("^(https?://)?www.",websitm[, 2], ig=T), "", "http://www."),websitm[, 2])
websitm$Website <- paste0(ifelse(grepl("^https?://",websitm[, 2], ig=T), "", "http://"),websitm[, 2])

Httpcode<- function(x){try(HEAD(x, timeout(seconds = 20), silent = T))}
websitm$error<- apply(websitm[,2, drop=F], 1, Httpcode)
websitm$outcome<- sapply(websitm$error, function(x) if (inherits(x, "try-error")) -999 else status_code(x))
websitm<- data.frame(lapply(websitm, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```