# checking website status of multiple urls using lapply- error handling

Tags: r, url, lapply

I want to check the status of multiple websites (appr. 8,000).

I found this great example:
[checking validity of a list og urls using GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915316/checking-validity-of-a-list-og-urls-using-get)

```
This solution uses this code: 
websites <- read.table(header=T, text="website
1   www.msn.com
2   www.wazl.com
3  www.amazon.com
4 www.rifapro.com")
library(httr)
urls <- paste0(ifelse(grepl("^https?://", websites$website, ig=T), "", "http://"),
          websites$website)
lst <- lapply(unique(tolower(urls)), function(url) try(HEAD(url), silent = T))
names(lst) <- urls
sapply(lst, function(x) if (inherits(x, "try-error")) -999 else status_code(x))
```

However, for some websites this takes ages, e.g. if I use http://www.chewy.com instead of www.wazl.com.

Here are some example links which work fine if I exclude the last chewy-link:

```
501 http://www.bedrockdata.com
502 http://www.beecroftortho.com
503 http://secure.beenevaluated.com
504 http://beercitizen.com
951 http://www.chewy.com
```

Why is that? My first idea is to use a timeout function but I don't know where to implement it. I do not get any error message, the code just won't finish and I'll have to restart the R session.

Comment: What is *ages*? 5 mins? 5 hours? And what line takes that long: `lapply` or `sapply`? Try `tryCatch` instead: `tryCatch(HEAD(url), error = function(e) e)`

Comment: @Parfait "Ages" means I interrupted after 9 days so I don't know how long it would have taken in total to complete. I cannot exactly test if sapply is also part of the problem since the problem occurs within the lapply command. Using ```lstt <- lapply(unique(tolower(urlst)), function(url) tryCatch(HEAD(url), error = function(e) e)) ``` seems not to imporve speed (tried it for 30 min before interrupting, not nine days). Without the www.chewy.com link the command leads to all urls being classified as "S3: simple error".